# ORA-00904: "PREV_TEMP": invalid identifier with LAG function

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

Whats is wrong with this query?

It returns: 
`ORA-00904: "PREV_TEMP": invalid identifier`

```sql
SELECT Id, RecordDate, Temperature, LAG(Temperature) OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) as prev_temp
FROM Weather
WHERE Temperature > prev_temp;
```

SQL schema:

```sql
Create table If Not Exists Weather (Id int, RecordDate date, Temperature int)
Truncate table Weather
insert into Weather (Id, RecordDate, Temperature) values ('1', '2015-01-01', '10')
insert into Weather (Id, RecordDate, Temperature) values ('2', '2015-01-02', '25')
insert into Weather (Id, RecordDate, Temperature) values ('3', '2015-01-03', '20')
insert into Weather (Id, RecordDate, Temperature) values ('4', '2015-01-04', '30')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use directly, but need to use in a subquery to be able to use the returning value from analytic function

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT Id, RecordDate, Temperature, 
          LAG(Temperature) OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) as prev_temp
     FROM Weather
  )
  WHERE Temperature > prev_temp;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Could you please explain why we should use subquery and why query listed in question does not work?

Comment: @raiym you're welcome. Since they're computed columns depending on the related columns of the table. i.e they're results actually.

Comment: I would say "because they are computed columns depending on related **rows** of the table". This is really the central point of the issue; if the computations depended only on other columns (within the same row), there would be no issue using the expression in `WHERE` (but, of course, without an alias - the expression would have to be repeated). Because analytic functions depend on other **rows**, they **can't** be used in `WHERE` at the same level as the `SELECT` even if they are spelled out in full rather than by alias.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with the query is that column aliases cannot be re-used in the `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `FROM`, or `GROUP BY` clauses where they are defined.  This applies to window functions, as well as everything else.  And this is a rule in *SQL*, not *Oracle* (although some databases relax the restriction on `GROUP BY`).

In your case, there are basically two solutions, a subquery and a CTE:

```
WITH w AS (
      SELECT w.*,
             LAG(Temperature) OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) as prev_temperature
      FROM weather w
     ) 
SELECT Id, RecordDate, Temperature,  prev_temp
FROM w
WHERE Temperature > prev_temp;
```

Comment: There are really TWO issues. In many cases, you can work around an alias issue without subqueries, by simply repeating the expression as is in the `WHERE` clause (or the other clauses). Alas, that's not the case for analytic functions - even without an alias, they can't be used in other clauses (except `ORDER BY`, which is evaluated after `SELECT`). Note also that "subquery and CTE" are not really two solutions - a CTE is a "factored **subquery**".

Comment: I also doubt that any databases relax the restriction on aliases specifically for `GROUP BY`. Can you suggest any examples? Or are you mixing it up with `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @mathguy . . . MySQL (and hence MariaDB), BigQuery, Hive, Postgres (and hence a bunch of Postgres-derived databases).  It is pretty standard practice for non-legacy databases.